# How to debug in VS Code by attaching to Edge browser?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, vscode-debugger

1. I have installed javascript debugger for Edge browser in my VSCode
2. It modifies the launch.json file like this.

```
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Attach to Edge",
        "port": 9222,
        "request": "attach",
        "type": "pwa-msedge",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

3. I have started the edge browser and enabled remote debugging on specified port through this command.

> start msedge.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222

I am getting the following error

[image: vscode error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of JavaScript Debugger and Edge browser are you using? I test with **JavaScript Debugger v1.57.0** and **Edge browser Version 91.0.864.59**, it works well.

Have you launched the page you want to debug in Edge first before you start to debug in VS Code? `"request": "attach"` means attaching the debug to an existing instance. For example, I need to debug this page `https://localhost:44364/test.html`, then I'll navigate to this url in Edge after `start msedge.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222`. The result is like this:

[image]

---

**Update:**

If you're using [Debugger for Microsoft Edge](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-edge), you can use the `launch.json` like below, then do what I said in the previous answer:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "edge",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach to Edge",
      "port": 9222,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note:** Please install the latest version of Visual Studio. Debugging Microsoft Edge (Chromium) is supported for VS versions >= 15.9.19.

Comment: I have installed extension for VSCode i.e Javascript debugger for edge v 1.0.15 and edge browser is latest 91.0.864.59

Comment: @Harkiratsingh I see, you're using [Debugger for Microsoft Edge](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-edge), not [JavaScript Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeOUo.png). The launch setting for Debugger for Microsoft Edge should be `"type": "edge"`, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/visual-studio-code/debugger-for-edge) for more information. You can check my updated answer and tell us if the issue has been fixed after trying.

Comment: It says that debug type is not recognized when I change back to edge

Comment: @YuZhou the link to the debugger for edge is no longer valid, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge extension APIs don't support promises as stated in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-apis).

If it's an option, you could use callbacks in your app instead of promises..

Also see issue on github [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/688) and [there](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/2764).

Answer (score 0):

1. I uninstalled Debugger for microsoft Edge extension and reinstalled it
2. Then I disabled Javascript debugger extension globally.
3. I closed all instances of edge browser and ran the following command.

> start msedge.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222

4. Attached debugger and added breakpoint and it started working.